When inserting a reference image by dragging it in, why does it disappear if I rotate the camera?
I inserted an image for reference in Blender 4.2 as I am trying to learn to make models for rigging. Thing is, the image can be modified just fine when in the plane it was inserted (+X), but when the camera is rotated, even with the image selected, I can see the center point but the image becomes unmodifiable and non-visible at all until I return to the view it was inserted at (+X). Why does this happen and how can I fix it? Sorry if it is obvious, I've just started learning blender and any help is really appreciated.

When you drag and drop an image into an orthographic view it is only shown for orthographic views. That's because it is assumed you only want to see it in that view and you don't want it to get in the way when navigating in the scene which might be desirable in most cases. You can enable Show in Perspective in the Properties Editor, Data tab, Empty panel when you have the image selected in the viewport or Outliner:

